# Unable to run server and error displayed in command prompt

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I am trying to open the web page with the code followed in github and unable to run the server facing the errors and displayed in command prompt as below:

Code link: https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/nodejs-basics-tutorial/tree/master/09-mongodb

Error:

05-express-first-app@0.0.0 start C:\Users\Atchaya\Downloads\nodejs-basics-tutorial-master\09-mongodb

> node ./bin/www

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Atchaya\Downloads\nodejs-basics-tutorial-master\09-mongodb\app.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! 05-express-first-app@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the 05-express-first-app@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the 05-express-first-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 05-express-first-app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 05-express-first-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Atchaya\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-04-19T14_14_54_505Z-debug.log
```

Comment: did you do `npm install` in `09-mongodb` folder?

Comment: @Dan I don't think they did `npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go you your `09-mongodb` folder, then run `npm install` command, then run `npm run start`.

`npm install`  -

> This command installs a package, and any packages that it depends on.
>   If the package has a shrinkwrap file, the installation of dependencies
>   will be driven by that.
>
> By default, npm install will install all modules listed as
>   dependencies in package.json.

Comment: It worked well... and able to run the server...thanks for your reply and answer...